# JSON Schema to return a list from one or more items selected

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am trying to define a JSON Schema that will allow the user to select one or more values from a fixed list. Let's say I have a property "columns", e.g.:

```
http://a.xyz/resource?columns=col1,col2
```

I define this to return an array, but I also want

```
http://a.xyz/resource?columns=col3
```

to be valid, returning a single element array. I have this:

```
"properties": {
    "columns": {
        "oneOf": [
            {
                "type": "array",
                "uniqueItems": true,
                "minItems": 2,
                "items": {
                    "type":"string",
                    "enum": ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]
                }
            },
            {
                "type":"string",
                "enum": ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]
            }   
        ]
    }
}
```

but I have to coerce the result into an array if one element is selected. Worse, a query like this:

```
http://a.xyz/resource?columns=col3,blah
```

doesn't report that "blah" is not a column, as it would if I removed the second block above.